# Is there a way to dynamically build an sql query

Tags: python, sqlite

I am coding a database manager in Python using SQLite3 and tkinter, and I am attempting to build a query function. Each element in my database has several attributes: 'name', 'path', 'seen', 'quality', 'franchise', 'genre' and 'tags'.

If possible, I want the user to be able to select certain options in the GUI and then create a request to the database, but the problem is that **the user should be able to select any or all of those attributes to be filtered out or into the query**. For example, one query might be asking for all the objects in the database with the name "Tony", franchise "toy Story", and genre "Action", whereas another query might just want all objects of seen "yes".

I've been having a lot of trouble with this, and though I've been tempted to, I can't hardcode every permutation of parts of the SQL Select statement, and I feel like there's a better way anyways I can't see. I've tried setting a 'default statement':
`SELECT * FROM objects WHERE` and then adding onto it like `genre IS ?` and if franchise matters than   `AND franchise IS ?`, but then I run into the problem of I don't know how to format the substitutions dynamically. I'm pretty sure this can be done, so I'd love any help. Thanks!

Comment: use https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/# to properly build dynamic queries, using string concatenation is not advised

Comment: @gold_cy why is string concatenation a bad idea?

Comment: better to let a well tested library handle the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right path.  Consider building up a list of WHERE clauses and a parallel list of substitutions.  In this example, I'm using strings, but you get the idea:

```
subs = []
where = []
where.append( "name = ?" )
subs.append( "Tony" )
where.append( "franchise = ?" )
subs.append( "Toy Story" )

sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE " + (" AND ".join(where)) + ";"
query = cursor.execute( sql, subs )
```

Comment: You make it seem so easy haha, although why do you have semicolons added to the where statements? are those necessary?